How to control spatial autocorrelation

I want to control the spatial autocorrelation in my data. Following method used in this paper , I did the following:
# the whole earth is divided into grids whose area is 280km*280km
shapeFile <- "result/gridsShapeResult/edges280.shp"
grid <- read_sf(shapeFile)

# potential evapotranspiration for each of the grid
pet <- read_sf('result/envResult/shapeFiles/08_pet.shp') %>% st_drop_geometry()

# species richness for each grid
inputFile = paste0('result/spResult/07_birdPerGrid280.csv')
bird <- read_csv(inputFile) %>% group_by(gridNo) %>% summarise(SR=n())

# keep only grids have data with species richness and PET
petBird <- grid %>%
    inner_join(pet) %>%
    inner_join(bird) %>%
    filter(SR >= 10) # SpeciesRichness >= 10

# calculate the distance matrix of PET using the centroid of each grid
petBirdCenter <- petBird %>% st_centroid() %>% st_coordinates() %>% as_tibble()
petBirdCenterDist <- as.matrix(stats::dist(petBirdCenter))

mod <- mgcv::gam(SR ~ s(pet), data = petBird, family = poisson)
modRes <- mod$residuals
modResStd <- as.vector((modRes - mean(modRes)) / sd(modRes))
correl <- lets.correl(modResStd, petBirdCenterDist, 10, T)

# calculate Principal Coordinates of Neighbourhood Matrix
pcnm <- vegan::pcnm(petBirdCenterDist)
petBird$vect1 <- pcnm$vectors[, 1]
petBird$vect2 <- pcnm$vectors[, 2]
petBird$vect3 <- pcnm$vectors[, 3]
petBird$vect4 <- pcnm$vectors[, 4]
petBird$vect5 <- pcnm$vectors[, 5]
petBird$vect6 <- pcnm$vectors[, 6]
petBird$vect7 <- pcnm$vectors[, 7]
petBird$vect8 <- pcnm$vectors[, 8]

# repeat the model and check spatial autocorrelation again
mod <- mgcv::gam(SR ~ s(pet) + vect1 + vect2 + vect3 + vect4 + vect5 + vect6 +  vect7 + vect8, data = petBird, family = poisson)
modRes <- mod$residuals
modResStd <- as.vector((modRes - mean(modRes)) / sd(modRes))
correl <- lets.correl(modResStd, petBirdCenterDist, 10, T)

If I understand correctly, here the autocorrelation is a function of distance. However, in reality, consider point A with similar distances to points B and C. Although A, B, and C are all on land, there is an ocean between A and B, while A and C are connected by land. It is possible that A and C have similar species richness, whereas A and B could have very different species richness.
Should we also account for such environmental barriers if we only use distance to quantify autocorrelation?
If so, how to achieve that?

Instead of distance, you might need a measure of accessibility, such as travel time. Distance is easy and objective; accessibility is harder (requires a network graph) and more subjective (i.e. what mode of transport; is water passable, slowly or quickly, or impassable, etc.)

As an analyst, the distance measure you use to model correlation is your choice, and you justify it based on your domain knowledge.
You could draw a straight line between every pair of points and if the line goes through a wall you set the "distance" to infinite. Or if a line goes across 80% land and 20% water you could set the "distance" to 0.80xA + 0.2xB where you choose A and B depending on how hard it is to get across water and land.
Be careful though, because some methods require any distance measure to be a "metric" in the mathematical sense. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Metric.html - travel time using one-way streets isn't a metric, nor necessarily is the case of walls or other barriers. Arithmetical problems can arise if non-metric distance matrices are used by analysis methods that expect them to be metric.
